# How can I submit "amp-state" to webservice that I call on "action-xhr"?

Tags: php, web-services, amp-html

How can I submit "amp-state" to PHP webservice that I call on "action-xhr" ?

UPDATE:
Let me be specific: I have:

```html
<form method="post" action-xhr="some_web_service_url">
   <amp-state id="myState">
        <script type="application/json">
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
        </script>
  </amp-state>
.....
</form>
```

Now, how can I set **foo** from the **amp-state** as one of the arguments/values that I have in my "post" request to "some_web_service_url"? 
I need to pick the value **from the amp-state** and I **cannot** set it to be **fixed**! 
**I cannot** set it in the url query string!

Comment: By programming it! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply binding to `[value]` on a hidden form field (make sure that your `value` matches the one from the initial state, since `amp-state` is not evaluated on load):

```
<amp-state id="myState">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<form method="post" action-xhr="some_web_service_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" [value]="myState.foo">
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code change action

```html
<!--  in action-xhr use your action url -->
 <form class="sky-form" method="post" action-xhr="<?=SITE_PATH?>/mailto.php" target="_top"  name="enquiry">
 <!--  here add your input field -->
 </form>
```